# Quick Launch disappears after restarting

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, quicklaunch

Every time I turn on my Windows 7 computer, the Quick Launch disappears. I have to add it manually to the taskbar every time.

I had this problem on my last Windows 7 (64bit) machine. And now on my 32bit version of Windows 7, I have the same problem!

How can I prevent Quick Launch disappearing after a reboot?

Comment: Hm? Win7 does not have quick launch panel. What did you mean?

Comment: @maximus I added it manually as mentioned here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Microsoft has made available a hotfix that will resolve a problem
>   where the taskbar customizations are lost and reset to defaults when
>   [automatic logon](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/377-log-automatically-startup.html) is enabled in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008
>   R2. More details are available at [FIX: The Taskbar is reset to the
>   default settings when you use the "Automatically Log On" feature in
>   Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979155).
>
> If you still have the issue of where the pinned Quick Launch used in
>   this tutorial disappears on you after logging off and on or restarting
>   the computer, then a workaround for this issue is to either:
>
> - [Save your current theme](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/280-theme-change-save.html) after adding Quick Launch.
> - If you have a **32-bit Windows 7**, then it has been reported that you may need to [turn off UAC](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/299-user-account-control-uac-change-notification-settings.html) if Quick Launch is disappearing on
>     you after every restart.
> - Open the hidden **Quick Launch** folder in the NOTE box below, then right click in the folder and click on **New** and **Shortcut** to add
>     a shortcut into Quick Launch instead.
> - Create a new folder, copy the shortcuts in the Quick Lauch folder above into the new folder, then [pin the new folder to the taskbar](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/9305-taskbar-pin-unpin-folder.html)
>     instead just like the Quick Launch folder here.
> - To use a Microsoft **hotfix**. It is intended to correct only the problem that is described in this article. Apply it only to systems
>     that are experiencing this specific problem.
>
>   Information: [FIX: The Taskbar is reset to the default settings when
>     you use the "Automatically Log On" feature in Windows 7 and in Windows
>     Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979155)     Download link: [Help and Support](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=979155&kbln=en-us)
>
> NOTE: Quick Launch is used to open a program quickly from a shortcut
>   on the taskbar. In this case in a toolbar The Quick Launch folder is
>   located at the [hidden system folder location](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/394-hidden-files-folders-show-hide.html) (step 2) of:
>
> **`C:\Users\(user-name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`**

<sub>Source: [sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/888-quick-launch-enable-disable.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

In any folder, Click **"Tools" (in the Menu bar) → click "Folder Options" → click "View" tab, in "Advanced Settings"** list, find and check mark **"Remember each folder's view settings"** (also, ensure that **"Do not cache Thumbnails"** is not checked).

Then,set the view of any folder as you want, then go to the "View" tab in "Folder Options", and click the "Apply to all folders" button. If this won't solve your problem, then use this:

click **Start → Run**  (or from **C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32** open CMD with "RUN AS ADMIN") 

and enter these 2 commands one by one:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_Current_User\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer" /v "NoSaveSettings" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f


REG ADD "HKEY_Local_Machine\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer" /v "NoSaveSettings" /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
```

Then restart the computer.

After windows logon, ensure that the Quick Launch Toolbar is ticked via right click on Taskbar → toolbar → tick quick launch.

Thanks so much to Correz and Rainna.